# Disk and/or Washer Methods

Tags: calculus

Using disks or washers, find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2$ and $y^2=x$ about the x-axis.

For this problem I switched $y^2=x$ with $y=\sqrt x$ and therefore tried using the washer method making my outer curve $y=\sqrt x$ and the inner curve $y=x^2$. My formula was then at Vwasher= $\pi(\sqrt  x -x^2)dx$ I know I need to find the limits of integration after this point but I cant seem to find them with these curves.

Id appreciate any help!

Comment: The limits would be given by those points where the curves intersect. ie. $y = \sqrt{x} = x^2$.

Comment: Yes I knew that however I cant make out any numbers when set equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

Draw the two parabolas. By symmetry they meet where $y=x$, and therefore where $x^2=x$, that is, $x=0$ and $x=1$.

The "upper" curve is $y=\sqrt{x}$, the lower curve is $y=x^2$. Thus a cross-section perpendicular to the $x$-axis is a "washer" with outer radius $\sqrt{x}$ and inner radius $x^2$. It follows that the volume is
$$\int_0^1 \pi \left((\sqrt{x})^2-(x^2)^2\right)\,dx.$$

**Remark:** You can think of the formula as follows. We take the region below $y=\sqrt{x}$, and above the $x$-axis. The volume generated by this shape is
$$\int_0^1 \pi (\sqrt{x})^2\,dx.$$
But our actual shape has a hole in it, obtained by rotating the region below $y=x^2$. The hole has volume
$$\int_0^1\pi (x^2)^2\,dx.$$